# Stop Selenium WebDrvier Test in Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am using Selenium WebDriver in Jmeter. Now when I come across any error, such as text of an element does not match, I would like to stop the execution of the test.

```
var ele1 = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector('<element>')).getText();
var ele2 = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector('<another_element>')).getText();
var ele3 = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector('<another_element>')).getText();

if(ele.localeCompare('text') && ele2.localeCompare('UP') && ele3.localeCompare('UP') )
{
    WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
    WDS.sampleResult.setResponseMessage('Error found, text not matching');
    WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
}
```

This doesn't stop the test, but continue to execute the remaining code. Is there a way to stop the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these 3 lines:

```
WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
WDS.sampleResult.setResponseMessage('Error found, text not matching');
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

with this one:

```
throw new Error('Error found, text not matching')
```

It will generate a [runtime error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) which will stop all the further execution, no code below this line will be ever run.

More information on WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! Also, is there a way, to continue the test, and display all the errors at the end? I mean, can i append all my error messages and display them using setResponseMessage?

Comment: Never mind, I just appended all my errors and set that as response message. Anyway, thanks for your help :)